# Connect a signal to a bound method

Tags: django

I'm trying to connect django's post_save signal to a bound instance method, but it doesn't get called. The code is:

```
for adapter_class in signal_adapters:
    adapater_instance = adapter_class(definition_class)
    for signal in adapter_class.signals:
        signal.connect(adapater_instance.signal_reciever, sender=action_object_class)
```

If I decorate `signal_receiver` with `@classmethod` it works ok. There's this comment in the source of the `connect` method, which led me to believe it should be possible to connect bound methods as well:

> receiver - A function or an instance method which is to receive signals.

I guess I could curry the static version of `signal_receiver`, passing it instance as a parameter, and use this as a receiver, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to also pass "weak=False" in connect method. So your code should be like:

```
for adapter_class in signal_adapters:
    adapater_instance = adapter_class(definition_class)
    for signal in adapter_class.signals:
        signal.connect(adapater_instance.signal_reciever, sender=action_object_class, weak=False)
```

Comment: Wouldn't this mean that that method never gets cleaned up though, even if the instance object goes out of scope?